# How to process Python dictionary keys in a for loop while also adding new keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary where we have multiple types of keys (in this case, keyType1 and keyType2):

```
    example_dict = {
        "keyType2[3]": 23,
        "keyType2[-1]": -21,
        "keyType2[-2]": -22,
        "keyType1[0]": 0,
        "keyType1[2]": 2,
        "keyType1[-1].subkey1": -11,
        "keyType1[-1].subkey2": -12,
        "keyType1[-2].subkey1": -21,
        "keyType1[-2].subkey2": -22,
        "keyType1[-3]": -3,
    }
```

and they are indexed, like in a list. My task is to identify the negatively indexed keys in the dictionary, find the maximum value of the index for same type of keys, and recalculate the negative indices based on that maximum value.

What I have:

```
def example_implementation(example_dict):
    negative_keys = filter(lambda x: re.search(r"\[-\d+\]", x), example_dict.keys())
    for key in negative_keys:
        indexed_key, index = re.search(r"(?P<indexed_key>.*?)\[-(?P<index>\d+)\]", key).groups()
        indexed_keys = [key for key in example_dict.keys() if indexed_key in key]
        max_index = max(
            map(lambda x: int(re.search(f"{re.escape(indexed_key)}\[([\d-]+)\]", x).group(1)), indexed_keys,)
        )
        if max_index < 0:
            # no non-negative list elements were found
            raise exceptions.KeyError
        key_mappings = filter(
            lambda x: x[0] != x[1],
            (
                map(
                    lambda x: (x, x.replace(f"{indexed_key}[-{index}]", f"{indexed_key}[{max_index + 1}]"),),
                    indexed_keys,
                )
            ),
        )
        for (old_key, new_key) in key_mappings:
            example_dict[new_key] = example_dict.pop(old_key)
    return example_dict
```

The implementation I have works for:

```
    example_dict = {
        "keyType1[-1].subkey1": -11,
        "keyType1[-1].subkey2": -12,
        "keyType1[0]": 0,
        "keyType1[2]": 2,
        "keyType1[-2]": -2,
        "keyType2[3]": 3,
        "keyType2[-1]": 34,
    }
```

but not for

```
    example_dict = {
        "keyType2[3]": 23,
        "keyType2[-1]": -21,
        "keyType2[-2]": -22,
        "keyType1[0]": 0,
        "keyType1[2]": 2,
        "keyType1[-1].subkey1": -11,
        "keyType1[-1].subkey2": -12,
        "keyType1[-2].subkey1": -21,
        "keyType1[-2].subkey2": -22,
        "keyType1[-3]": -3,
    }
```

The output is:

```
{
        "keyType2[3]": 23,
        "keyType2[-2]": -22,
        "keyType1[0]": 0,
        "keyType1[2]": 2,
        "keyType2[4]": -21,
        "keyType1[3].subkey1": -11,
        "keyType1[3].subkey2": -12,
        "keyType1[4].subkey1": -21,
        "keyType1[4].subkey2": -22,
        "keyType1[5]": -3,
    }
```

Notice the second key did not get processed.
I can't figure out what the issue is. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `and recalculate the negative indices based on that maximum value.`? I am looking into it but I don't see how you get the output of the first example_dict following the above logic.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 the idea of reassigning indices is to end up with list-like representation of the indexed keys, and the negatively indexed keys are appended at end of that list. so regardless of the order of the negative indices, you find the largest index for that type of key at each run and add 1, so then that element would be appended afterwards